# hilt: Inject generic interface with generic implementation with kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics, dagger-hilt

I'm new in kotlin and i'm trying to inject a generic interface with hilt but i get the following error:
`error: @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type public abstract com.apppackage.domain.repository.localdata.UserRepository bindUserRepository(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`

my generic interface code:

```
interface LocalDataRepository<T> {
    suspend fun insert(model: T)
    suspend fun update(model: T)
    suspend fun delete(model: T)
    suspend fun selectById(id: Long): T
    suspend fun selectAll(): List<T>
    suspend fun insertAll(data: List<T>)
}
```

my generic implementation class:

```
open class LocalDataImpl<T: BaseEntity>(private val dao: BaseDao<T>) : LocalDataRepository<T> {

    override suspend fun insert(model: T) {
        dao.insert(model)
    }

    override suspend fun insertAll(data: List<T>) {
        dao.insertAll(data)
    }

    override suspend fun update(model: T) {
        dao.update(model)
    }

    override suspend fun delete(model: T) {
        dao.delete(model)
    }

    override suspend fun selectById(id: Long): T {
        return dao.getEntityById(id)
    }

    override suspend fun selectAll(): List<T> {
        return dao.getAll()!!
    }
}
```

My entity implementation code:

```
interface UserRepository: LocalDataRepository<UserEntity> {
}

class UserRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val userDao: UserDao): LocalDataImpl<UserEntity>(userDao) {

}
```

**this is my module**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class LocalDataRepositoryModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindUserRepository(impl: UserRepositoryImpl): UserRepository
}
```

and my usecase:

```
class StoreUserInfoInDb @Inject constructor(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
) {
    suspend fun invoke(model: UserModel) {
        try {
            val id = userRepository.insert(model.toEntity())
            Log.i("LOCAL_DB", "Successfull, entity id: $id")
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.i("LOCAL_DB", e.message.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks if someone can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it extending the interface in the impl:

```
interface UserRepository: LocalDataRepository<UserEntity> {
}

class UserRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val userDao: UserDao): UserRepository, LocalDataImpl<UserEntity>(userDao) {

}
```

I don't know if is the best practices but it's working for me

Answer (score 1):

Return type of `bindUserRepository` is `UserRepository` but its parameter is `UserRepositoryImpl` of type `LocalDataImpl<UserEntity>(userDao)`.

In `@Binds` method's parameter must be of its return type:

```
class UserRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val userDao: UserDao): LocalDataImpl<UserEntity>(userDao) {

}
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class LocalDataRepositoryModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindUserRepository(impl: UserRepositoryImpl): UserRepository
}
```

In bind method parameter must be implementation of return type. But your code has not followed this rule.